# Set color of customized title page \usebeamerfont{author,institute} sections only

Tags: beamer

For the following Beamer Code I would like to change only the color of the Author and Institute sections only to black. And leave the others blue. How can I achieve this?

Thanks
R

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{customized}[1][]
{
\usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\inserttitle\par
\bigskip
\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par
\bigskip
 \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par
\bigskip
\usebeamerfont{institute}{\tiny \insertinstitute}\par
\bigskip
\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par
\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic
}

\centering

\title{Blah Blah Blah}
\subtitle{Blah Blah Blah Blah}
\author{Someone}
\institute[University of]{

\inst{1}%
 Department of Stuff\\
 University of Someplace
 \and
\inst{2}%
 Department of Stuff\\
 University of Somplace~\\
}
\date{\today}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a side comment: `centering` will affect all your slides. If you want it applies only to title frame, insert it into title page declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And here's a solution *à la beamer*. 
The **simplest** beamer solution is to simply change the font color before the `\insertauthor` command and then change it back before the `\insertdate`

Use `\usebeamercolor[black]{}` to change to black and then `\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}` to change the color back (to the same color as the title).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{customized}[1][]
{
\usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\inserttitle\par
\bigskip
\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par
\bigskip
 \usebeamerfont{author}\usebeamercolor[black]{}\insertauthor\par
\bigskip
\usebeamerfont{institute}{\tiny \insertinstitute}\par
\bigskip
\usebeamerfont{date}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\insertdate\par
\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic
}

\centering

\title{Blah Blah Blah}
\subtitle{Blah Blah Blah Blah}
\author{Someone}
\institute[University of]{

\inst{1}%
 Department of Stuff\\
 University of Someplace
 \and
\inst{2}%
 Department of Stuff\\
 University of Somplace~\\
}
\date{\today}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

One not *à la beamer* solution: insert `\textcolor{black}{...}` in `\author` and `\institute` declarations. Although this solution will probably affect also colors for author in headers or footers.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{customized}[1][]
{
\usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\inserttitle\par
\bigskip
\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par
\bigskip
 \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par
\bigskip
\usebeamerfont{institute}{\tiny \insertinstitute}\par
\bigskip
\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par
\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic
}

\centering

\title{Blah Blah Blah}
\subtitle{Blah Blah Blah Blah}
\author{\textcolor{black}{Someone}}
\institute[University of]{
\textcolor{black}{
\inst{1}%
 Department of Stuff\\
 University of Someplace
 \and
\inst{2}%
 Department of Stuff\\
 University of Somplace~\\}
}
\date{\today}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

*2nd version: à la beamer*

Another version a little bit different from what Grimler proposed. This one proposes to fit `author` and `institute` colors with

```
\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{institute}{fg=black}
```

and use them in your `title page` declaration:

```
\usebeamerfont{author}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{author}\insertauthor}\par
\usebeamerfont{institute}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute}\tiny \insertinstitute}\par
```

With the `default` title page declaration, just fixing author and institute colors would be enough because it uses `\beamercolorboxes` to insert them, but your `customized` version don't do it.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I used the first answer. However, I can see when your answer can be useful as well. Thank you again.